# Truffle interaction with my smart contract getting Vm exception

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Hotelbooking {

  event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

 mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;


  //mapping (uint256 => data) accounts ;


  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
          require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

          balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;

          balanceOf[_to] += _value;

          Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;

      }
    }
```

My trascation code i want intract with mty truffle

> Hotelbooking.deployed().then(function(i){app = i;})
>
> app.transfer(web3.eth.accounts[1],10,{from : web3.eth.accounts[0] })

i am getting the following error

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)

plese help me

Comment: How much does `accounts[0]` have in `balanceOf`?

Comment: it  is having 99.69  ether it is a test network

Comment: No no, I am talking about `mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;`. How much does `app.balanceOf(web3.eth.accounts[0] )` return?

Comment: It is Showing me app.balanceOf(web3.eth.accounts[0] )
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] } (i tried to convert into the .tonumber())

Comment: It looks like it is `0`. do `.toString(10)`. In effect `balanceOf[msg.sender] == 0`, so it fails at `require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);`.

Comment: sorry i am confused that i am thinking i am transferring the ether from one account to another ,
In ganache my testnetwork is showing that i am having 99 ether
Can you plese help me where i went wrong

Comment: Your `Hotelbooking` is a token contract. It has balances and a transfer function. It has nothing to do with Ether. Look up "token contract". As it stands, everybody has 0 tokens in your contract, so nobody can send anything. You need to initialise it.

Comment: Thanks 

I got it i taught same code can work for  writting erc20  tokens and etherium trascation   eth.getBalance and add the amount eth.send() to deduct the balance

Answer (score 0):

Your balances are all zero. The require in your transfer function will always fail. You're missing a constructor to mint some coins.

E.g.:

```
constructor(uint initialAmount) {
     balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialAmount;
}
```

Comment: HI ivicaa 
I taught  i have found the issue please correct  me if i was wrong 
Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue .The function which i mentioned is for transferring my coins to another account rather than ether of one account to another

To Transfer ether see the following link

[I am trying to add ether to one of my etherium account using smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60325/i-am-trying-to-add-ether-to-one-of-my-etherium-account-using-smart-contract)